# Excel vba - change format of date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with **dates** that are stored as `d.m.yyyy. h:mm:ss`.

And the cell format isn't even **date** it's **general**.
To use it as a date I need to replace that dot with `""`.
So I used this code:

```
Format(Date, "d.m.yyyy h:mm:ss")
```

But it changed all dates to todays date.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate more.

Comment: The cell values look like a date, but they're not.  If you do A2 - A1, it returns #value! error. They are probably strings. To change them to dates, I can't even do it manually with format cells option in excel. I need to do it with "replace" and replace "2017." with "2017" and then it works.

Answer (score 2):

The call of `Date` returns the current date. You have to use the cell value instead, like `Format(Cells(row,column), "d.m.yyyy h:mm:ss")`, after you replaced the dot at the end of the year value.

Comment: Thanks, I used it like this:    `For Each c In Selection`
        `c.Value = Format(c, "d.m.yyyy h:mm:ss")`
     `Next c`